# Not able to share internet connection over wireless lan

Tags: networking, router, connection-sharing

I have an ethernet line which runs from a switch (which belongs to my ISP) at the top of my apartment building to my desktop computer(WinXP) LAN card.

Now I have another DSL braodband connection which connects to my wireless router (Linksys WAG120N adsl2 router/modem) . All my other laptops(Win 7) are connected to the DSL connection through WLAN.

I wanted to share the former internet connection to my other laptops (because its faster). So I connected the ISP's ethernet cable to my router and created and shared the connection from my desktop PC using ICS.

But none of my laptops or other devices can connect to the internet. They work if I connect them using LAN cables but not wirelessly.

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong here.

Or can you suggest any other method.

Comment: So, you're connecting the ISP connection to the router, but sharing through the desktop?  Why are you sharing it from your desktop when the router itself would share it?  Or am I misunderstanding...

Comment: The router does not automatically connect to the ISP. I have to connect manually through my desktop using the PPPoE connection dialog.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Some routers have a PPPoE login function, does yours?  If not, I'm assuming your desktop has a wireless adapter of some kind.  You'd need a way to manage the wireless network, which in XP I believe is limited to ad hoc mode.  Have you tried configuring an ad hoc wireless network yet?

Comment: My router has a PPPoE login function but it does not connect automatically.My desktop does not have a wireless adapter.

Comment: It sounds like to do what you want to do, you'd have to obtain a wireless adapter -- OR -- buy a 2nd NIC or USB ethernet adapter, set up ICS between them, connect the ISP to the first ethernet port, then connect the second one to a LAN port on the router, and set the router up as an access point.  Unless there's a way to get your router to cooperate better with PPPoE, I can't think of a way to do what you are asking without an extra piece of hardware somewhere.